# What books/tutorials are available on the topic of Couchbase lite for iOS?

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am a new developer using Couchbase Lite in iOS with the language Swift. I've read the documentation multiple times, however, I am still left confused on how to take advantage of views and queries. I have found one resource, Pro Couchbase Server, which only provided one minimally detailed section on Couchbase Lite for iOS. Are there any resources, other than what I have mentioned, for understanding how to properly structure views and make complicated queries?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just so you know, asking for off-site resources is explicitly off-topic as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try doing some more research on your own for this topic - most people learn better this way! If you find you have a specific programming question, go ahead and post a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

They Couchbase Mobile Developer portal is a great resource for learning about [Views](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html) and [Queries](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html).

And can look at the [Couchbase Mobile forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/mobile) for other specific questions too.